# Javascript - How to define a class in multiple modules?

Tags: javascript, oop, refactoring, ecmascript-5

I have a class, which is becoming really long. I have identified multiple different concepts that, together, they give meaning to my class.

"**MyService**" class is composed by: "**auth**", "**storage**", "**database**", ... concepts.

I have thought (maybe I am wrong) that defining the class "MyService" in multiple files will be a good refactoring. Something like:

*MyService/MyService.js*
import myService from "./myService";

```
export default function MyService() {
     if(!isInitialized) {
         myService.initializeApp(config);

         // Only after doing myService.initializeApp(config);
         this.auth = myService.auth();
         this.storage = myService.storage();
         this.database = myService.database();

         isInitialized = true;
     }
}
```

*MyService/Auth.js*

```
Add auth methods to MyService class prototype
```

*MyService/Storage.js*

```
Add storage methods to MyService class prototype
```

...

How can I do that? Does this technique has a name/exists? Is it a good way to refactor my class? If yes, why? And if not, then, why?

Thank you.

### UPDATE

Maybe, splitting the class into smaller classes is the best idea, but I don't know how to make it work as for accessing myService functionalities,
this line

```
myService.initializeApp(config);
```

must have been previously executed on a singleton.

### EXAMPLE BASED IN THE SOLUTION

```js
/* Simulate myService CLI SDK */
function myService() {}

myService.key = undefined;

myService.initializeApp = function (key) {
  this.key = key;
} 

myService.auth = function () {
  if(!this.key) {
    throw new Error("Please, initialize app");
  }

  console.log(`You have access to all auth methods! Key: ${this.key}`);
}

myService.storage = function () {
  if(!this.key) {
    throw new Error("Please, initialize app")
  }

  console.log(`You have access to all storage methods! Key: ${this.key}`);
}



/* Classes that compose the main class */

function Auth() {
  this.auth = myService.auth();
}

Auth.prototype.login = function (username, password) {
  console.log("Login!");
}

function Storage() {
  this.storage = myService.storage();
}

Storage.prototype.uploadFile = function (file, path) {
  console.log("Uploading file!")
}




/* Main class */

let isInitialized = false;
function Firebase() {
  if(!isInitialized) { // Singleton
    myService.initializeApp("raul");
    this.auth = new Auth(); // Composition
    this.storage = new Storage(); // Composition
    isInitialized = true;
  }
}

const f = new Firebase();
f.auth.login();
f.storage.uploadFile();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of spreading `MyService` across multiple modules, you're probably better off breaking it into smaller classes. You've said:

> "MyService" class is composed by: "auth", "storage", "database", ... concepts.

so it may make sense to have a class for auth, another for storage, another for database, and then have `MyService` use instances of those other classes as part of its implementation.

<s>You can't spread a `class` definition across modules.</s> (Your edit shows that you're not using `class` syntax for some reason.) You *can* add near-methods to a class after the fact, like this:

```
class Example {
    // ...
}
```

Then in another module:

```
import Example from "./Example.js";

// (You'd probably have a utility method for this, `addMethod` or similar)
Object.defineProperty(Example.prototype, "methodName", {
    value() {
        // ...method implementation...
    },
    enumerable: false, // (You can leave this off, false is the default)
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
});
```

but it's probably not best practice to have the definition scattered around like that, and there are limitations, especially in subclasses (`super` in a method added this way will not work the way `super` in a method defined within the `class` definition would). (Your edit shows that you're not using `class` syntax, so that isn't relevant to you.)

So I would stick to breaking `MyService` into smaller classes that can be composed.

---

You may be wondering why I used `Object.defineProperty` above, rather than just:

```
Example.prototype.methodName = function() {
    // ...
};
```

The difference is *enumerability*. If you add a method using assignment like that, it creates an enumerable property, but if you use `Object.defineProperty` as shown above it doesn't. I'm using the same flags for `enumerable`, `configurable`, and `writable` that `class` definitions use when creating methods. Here's an example of the difference:

```js
class A { }
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, "example", {
    value() {},
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
});

class B { }
B.prototype.example = function() { };

const a = new A();
console.log(`typeof a.example = ${typeof a.example}`);
console.log(`a's enumerable non-Symbol properties:`);
let count = 0;
for (const name in a) {
    console.log(`* ${name}`);
    ++count;
}
console.log(`Total: ${count}`);

const b = new B();
console.log(`typeof b.example = ${typeof b.example}`);
console.log(`b's enumerable non-Symbol properties:`);
count = 0;
for (const name in b) {
    console.log(`* ${name}`);
    ++count;
}
console.log(`Total: ${count}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that `a` doesn't have any enumerable properties, but `b` does — because it inherits an

Comment: I thought to do this, but the main problem, in my use case, is that for accessing this.auth, this.storage or this.database, I have to make sure that myService.initializeApp(config) has been executed in my constructor's singleton.

Comment: @Raul - If `MyService` is a composition of smaller classes, I don't see why it couldn't do that after creating the instances of the other classes in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works! I have edited the question with an example based in the solution you described, can you check it is exactly what you described? Also, I am using prototype for simplicity, but I will move to the way you said!